# Appending arrays

Tags: java, arrays, append

I am trying to append two arrays together, so that the method will take in the current array, and then afterwards take in the second array and have the elements added to the end. Hopefully I am making sense.

Posting my attempt to code this method along with an example of what the output is, and what it is supposed to be.

EDIT: data is an instance variable within this class.

My code:

```
    public void append(double[] d)
{
    double[] temp = new double[data.length];
    for (int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }

    data= new double[temp.length+d.length];
    for (int z=0; z<temp.length; z++)
    {
        data[z]=temp[z];
    }

    for (int t=0; t<d.length;t++)
    {
        data[t]=d[t];
    }
}
```

My output:

```
 stat1 data = []  
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0]  
 stat1 data = [70.0, 80.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
 stat1 data = [90.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
 //null error comes
```

What it is supposed to be:

```
 stat1 data = []   
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0]   
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0]   
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0]   
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 100.0, 110.0]   
 stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 100.0, 110.0]  
 stat1 data = [100.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change the second part of your loop.

```
 for (int t=0; t<d.length;t++)
    {
        data[t+temp.length]=d[t];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for the second loop the counter should start from the end of data

```
int newCounter = 0;
for (int t=temp.lenght; t<data.length;t++)
{
    data[t]=d[newCounter++];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in array out of index for `d[t]`?

Comment: oops sorry .. made a mistake ,, changing it .. thanks @wns349